# Is there any port specific cookie in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies

When I'm running my project from visual studio's separate instance i.e. different port no then every thing is working fine but if I run only one instance of visual studio in different browser at the same time i.e. only one port on localhost but in different browser. then cookies are clashing. how to solve it? Please help. I'm developing my webapp in asp.net c#

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no such thing as a "port-specific" cookie. I suppose, theoretically, you could include port information *into* a cookie, and redirect a request to a site at that port, but there's nothing automatic about such a setup.

Comment: If it's the same type of browser then the cookie is shared, you should be able to use private browsing to get round this.

Comment: Could be the browser. In fact, could be a multitude of environment variables. Too broad.